# Angular JS : Selecting first radio button in dynamic data set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-checked

I have an array of objects over which I do orderby:"Attribute A" ,iterate over it using ng-Repeat and set ng-checked="$index === 0 ? true : false".

Now on same data on click Attribute B U do orderby : "Attribute B" and on click on C, orderby : "Attribute C",and iterate same as above and set ng-checked="$index === 0 ? true : false".

First radio button selection shows random behavior.

Any solution or suggestion for this?

Iterating on this :

```
   <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.sel_id" value="{{obj.uniq_id}}" ng-change="abc()" ng-checked="$index === 0 ? true : false" name="users" class="col-6" id="{{obj.uniq_id}}" >
```

Comment: Before asking an other question you may going to solve your question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050537/what-is-difference-in-ways-of-setting-radio-button-checked-true-in-angularjs. Some user give you input where you dont.

Comment: Well, before keep asking question, you may going to solve any of your questions. You did not mark the right answer on all questions you asked right now. Other users will help it when you mark the right answer, this is also how Stackoverflow works.